# How to implement a voting system in the play framework?

Tags: java, javascript, html, scala, playframework

I am trying to implement a voting system for questions / answers like SO or reddit. 
So far I have mocked some questions and answers. In there is a script with arrows for upvote / downvote that changes the color of the arrow and increases a number next to the arrow to indicate the number of votes.

But now I am stuck.

The mocked answers / questions need to be generated by a scala-template, not put in manually by me. I have no idea how to accomplish that.

Here is the script which colors the arrow and counts a vote:
(I have to mention that so far only the first of the arrows functions. This might be because the ID should be unique, so the second arrow will be ignored?)

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#icon').click(function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.css("color","orange");
            var num = $('#num');
            var currentNumber = num.text().length ? parseInt(num.text()) : 0;
            num.text(currentNumber + 1);
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is an example for some list entries of answers with arrows and a vote number that I've also put manually in:

```
<li class="list-group-item" > <span id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span><span id="num"></span> 7 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Die Schleife springt durch <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
<li class="list-group-item" > <span id="icon" class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></span><span id="num"></span> 1 <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></span> Das Programm hängt sich auf <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></li>
```

Here's a picture how it looks at the moment.

[image: Example for questions / answers / votes]

How do I proceed from here on? I'm pretty new to the play framework and it's scala templates, so maybe I can somehow let the framework generate a generic arrow / vote combination that I can process later instead of putting the lines manually in?
Do I have to somehow save the votes in a real database? 
How can I further process the votes i.e. how to put them into a variable?

There are several other questions on StackOverflow which are similar to mine, but almost none of them are using the play framework.

**[EDIT]:** Here is a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uxdp62v/), just click on the left-most arrow.

Comment: what do you mean by _need to be generated by a scala-template_? Do you want to generate the questions in your view? Do you want to retrieve them from the database and display them all in a generic way in your view?

Comment: English is not my first language, so I dont know how to say it better: I have hardcoded the html into the file to show some question / answer pairs. But as I was planning on using a database later on, I wanted to be able to get the questions and answers via the scala template itself. Now I have worked on it and have accomplished a DB, where I can store and retrieve the q/as and show them in my view. As I am not fully finished, I did not answer my own question yet.

Comment: Okay, the basic idea is: in your controller you can retrieve the questions/answers from the database, then you give them as parameters to your views. In the view you can iterate over the items - with `for` or even with `map`

Comment: I provided an answer with more explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say you have a class `Question` with one field 'text'

```
class Question {
    long id;
    String text;
}
```

And a class `Answer` with one field 'text'

```
class Answer {
    String text;
}
```

Now in your controller (maybe `Application.java`) first you get the Question and the corresponding Answers, then you give them to your view:

```
public static Result showQuestion() {
    Question q = Question.find.byId(1);
    List<Answer> possibleAnswers = Answer.findByQuestion(q);
    return ok(showquestion.render(q, possibleAnswers);
}
```

Now in your view you have this:

```
@(q: Question, answers: List[Answer])

<h3>@q.text</h3>

<ul>
@for(answer <- answers){
    <li>@answer.text</li>
}
</ul>
```

Of course the markup for the answers can be as complex as you like (with votes, arrows, icons and so on).

Comment: Thanks for the code, but since I've posted here I am already finished with most of those part of my project. :)

I have extracted 2 own classes, question and answer which I link via their ID. I've also written a view-class, that almost does what I want, I still need to save the voteScore into my DB, which sometimes does not work (see my other SO post that you have written in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30170304/why-is-bindfromrequest-using-the-wrong-form ).
All in all I am using the same approach that you have written here, so I'll accept your post as my answer.